# Vue is not re-rendering component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a Vue app with Vuex and 'vuex-persistedstate'. It's a kind of a "plugin" build as a library for any website. On my localhost everything works ok but problem happens when I attach my "plugin" to other websites.

I've got a component with list of products (array of objects) fetched via Axios and listed in table using for loop:

```
<tr v-for="product in products" :key="product.SKU">
...
</tr>
```

When I re-fetch other products and save them in `products`, table is not being re-rendered (Axios response is correct, new products are fetched and assigned to `proucts`). BUT... when I refresh website (I use persistedstate), new products are displayed. Only after refresh. They're not being re-rendered. Why?

EDIT:
Persistedstate has nothing to do with this. When I switched it off, my list was also not re-rendering. However... I've set `:key` to my table component which I increase every time Axios call is finished and it works.

Comment: you would have to give us more info like your vuex setup, how does it look when you fetch the proudcts ect..

Comment: can you please add more code? part of the vue app, maybe

Comment: Where is `products` defined? How do you _"re-fetch other products and save them in `products`"_